# Axios + Express.js delete, giving 404 with params

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I was expecting the delete call

```
const userDeleteHandler = (id: number) => {
  axios.delete('/admin/deleteUser/', {params: {UserID: id}})
  .then(response => {
         console.log(response);
   })
  .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
  })
};
```

to work, but got a consistent 404 error. After some digging here I tried

```
axios.delete('/admin/deleteUser/'+ id)
```

which worked. Why did my `params` attempt not work?

Here is my `server.ts` settings

```
import adminRoutes from './routes/admin';
const app = express();
app.options('*', cors()) // include before other routes
app.use(cors( {origin: true}));
app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
```

and the routes in my `routes/admin.ts`

```
router.get('/users', getAllUsers);
router.post('/newUser', postNewUser);
router.patch('/editUser', editUser);
router.delete('/deleteUser/:UserID', deleteUser);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios places the params like a query string with question marks (?). Therefore by using params, you are  sending a request to `/admin/deleteUser/?{id}` which is not found

Comment: aha, so the `params` in axios are query parameters, not path parameters?

Comment: Yes, for path params it is easy enough to just add it as a string to the original URL

Answer (score 1):

Because api is not found => 404

router.delete('/deleteUser/:UserID', deleteUser);
**(you getting value as a param but you sending value as a query. if you remove /:UserID then it will work)**

You should call like

axios.delete(`/admin/deleteUser/${id}`)
**(if you call API like above then it will work try this it will work definitely  )**

the reason not working is, You calling it only endpoint you should call API with-param (UserId is the param, not a query, just learn how to sent param value and query value this will make you understand )